# How to read array from other file?

Tags: python, arrays, file, iteration, line

I have a file (list.txt) with huge array like this:

```
['1458575', '1458576', '1458577', '1458578'...]
```

I want to read it in my script but the output is white. The goal is print the number of line (list.txt) of the file.txt

```
numbers_line = open("list.txt", "r")
lines = numbers_line.readlines().split(',')
i=0
f=open('file.txt')
for line in f:
    if i in lines:
        print (line)
    i+=1
```

However, if I  put the array direct it's read, but considering that is a huge array this is not could be helpful.

```
lines=['1458575', '1458576', '1458577', '1458578', '1458579', '1458580', '1458581', '1458582', '1458583', '1458584']
i=0
f=open('file.txt')
for line in f:
    if i in lines:
        print (line)
    i+=1
```

Thanks for your support

Comment: do you want to read array/list as a line or the the numbers one by one?

Comment: `i` is of type `int` and `lines` contains `str`s... they will never equate...

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15197673/6692898) shows how to convert a string containing a list to an actual list with `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @AnuragDhadse I want to read number by number present in the array (list.txt); this is the number of line that I want to print in other file(file.txt).

Comment: @RichieV thanks, but the list is integer numbers, maybe the variable name was wrong and confuse.

Comment: you are showing a list of strings `['1458575', '1458576', '1458577',...`, notice how the accepted answer needs to cast to a list of `int`s

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, you have right. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

readlines returns list of lines, not string

readline will return a string, but split(',') would give a list of string not int

try this

```
import ast
text_file = open("list.txt", "r")
lines = list(map(int, ast.literal_eval(text_file.read().strip())))
i=0
f=open('file.txt')
for line in f:
    if i in lines:
        print (line)
    i+=1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it doesn't work, the output file is white. What can I do about this?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I have edited my answer, you can try the current one, I chnaged ```list(map(int, ast.literal_eval(text_file.read().strip())))```

Answer (score 0):

This can work

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    content = file.read()
a = []
exec('a = ' + content)  # executes - a = ['1458575', ...]
```

Alternate method - copy file.txt to new file my_lists.py.
Add 'a = ' at the start of my_lists.py file and execute

```
from my_lists import a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `with open() as :` instead of `open()` and `close()`, because it closes the connection to file automatically when errors occurs while the traditional manual `open()` and `close()` don't do.

```
lines=['1458575', '1458576', '1458577', '1458578', '1458579', '1458580', '1458581', '1458582', '1458583', '1458584']
lines = [int(x) for x in lines] # convert to integers

fpath = "list.txt"

with open(fpath, "r") as f:
    for x in f:
        x = x.trim() # remove end of line character
        if int(x) in lines:
            print(x)
```